# CSS % for vertical margin based on width instead of height

Tags: html, css, margin

I wish to create a margin above my accountOrderButton so it can be centred vertically. I am trying to calculate half of the height of the parent div minus half of the child divs height.

This should center the button however the line 'margin-top: calc(50%);' in my CSS is returning the width of the parent div instead. How do I get the height?

**HTML**

```
<div id="accountOrder">
    <div id="accountOrderButton">
        Order Now!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#accountOrder {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#accountOrderButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: calc(50%);    <---- returns width instead of height
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: <?php echo $data['secondary_color']; ?>;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties: _“The percentage is calculated with respect to the **width** of the generated box's containing block. **Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.**”_ - What you want is not possible using CSS only. But there’s countless other ways to center elements, so do some research ... https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/, https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Also please note that `calc(50%)` is not calculating *anything at all* and is identical to `50%`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `top` instead of `margin-top`, without calc, also add `left: 50%;` and add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to move it back by half of its own height and width. This also requires to use absolute position on the child and relative position on the parent:

```
#accountOrder {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; /* added */
}
#accountOrderButton {
    position: absolute; /* added */
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 50%;  /* changed */
    left: 50%; /* added */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* added */
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: <?php echo $data['secondary_color']; ?>;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This is one of the standard ways to achieve vertical centering and as such, a valid solution for OP's problem. Nonetheless it fails to clarify the reason why OP's approach would not work.

Comment: Work so much with new methods, forgot about the classic way to center a div.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to align block elements, try to use [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Define a container element which holds the elements to align in any way you like. It would surely work with your % approach, but aligning items vertically is pretty easy with flexbox:

```
#accountOrder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You don't need any margins, positioning or something else. Please note that you must remove the `float: left;` as floating prevents flexbox from doing its thing.

To get a `float: left;` equivalent positioning with flexbox simply use:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As this is a common misunderstanding, it is probably worth turning @CBroe's comment into an answer so others find it easily.

> The **percentage is calculated** with respect to the **width** of the generated box's **containing block**. Note that this is true for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` as well.
>
> http://w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

Also please note that `calc(50%)` is not calculating *anything at all* and is identical to `50%`.